# Selenium webdriver to download pdf

Tags: java, selenium, pdf

Please look at the code below ( The pdf is embed in the website) I have to download using my selenium script.

```
    <embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" id="plugin" src="http://somewebsite/tulip.pdf" type="application/pdf" internalinstanceid="68" title="">
```

In the above html title = "" empty but when i hover on the embedded pdf download icon this value changes to title="Download" . How to use selenium to change this value automatically and download the pdf.   Fyi I am using google chrome and unable to directly download pdf.

Comment: See if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60854430/5885718

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get access to the download icon **somehow**:

```
WebElement downloadIcon = driver.findElement(By.tagName("embed"));
```

Extract the address of the PDF file:

```
String fileAddress = downloadIcon.getAttribute("src");
```

and then:

```
driver.get(fileAddress);
```

Comment: But wont the address chenge when i use different file ....the code wont be reusable

Comment: @Anu, it can be anything (no need for hardcoding). I have updated my answer.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: embed

Comment: @Anu, it was only an example. You should define your own way to locate this element.

Comment: @Anu how can i open pdf in browser with specific page number